# spyder console doesn't output the values from script

Tags: console

I am trying to see the output of my code in spyder but it doesn't outputs. I am using spyder 3.3.6. Its just few lines of code as following:

```
import pandas as pd
x_y_data = pd.read_csv("x_y_points400_labeled_csv.csv")
x = x_y_data.loc[:,'x']
y = x_y_data.loc[:,'y']
x_length=len(x)
x_length
x
```

it doesn't show anything and no error, 
but when i type in console, `x` or `print(x)` it does.

can you please help?

Comment: well i am expecting to give me a length of x column for example , which is 400, but why it doesn't show in output? yes i tried print(x) i meant to write in parenthesis

Comment: yes , i did in both , i just didn't mention it in my code